# How does reddit send email?

Tags: python, email, queue, message-queue, reddit

I am trying to learn how to large organisations that use python structure their code so that I can maybe apply some of their theories to my own code.

Currently I am looking through reddit's code and am interested how they have implemented the sending of emails generated as part of the app's operations. See: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/emailer.py (their emailing library) and  https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/models/mail_queue.py

I think mail_queue.py contains some form of SqlAlchemy table backed email queue. 
Is this the case. Does that mean the table is kept in memory? Could somebody make this a little clearer for me?

Cheers from Down Under.

P.S. May I suggest if anybody is trying to get a good understanding of how to structure python apps they do the same as I am. Reading and understanding other peoples code has allowed me to structure and write noticeably better code.. :) Open source stuff is great!

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the mail queue on e-mail servers has been some sort of disk storage. The reason for this is so that the chance of mail getting lost is minimized. For example, the mail server would receive a message and not send back a successful return code to the sending mail client until the entire message was successfully written to disk via synchronous write.

Yes, the reddit code is using a database as a email data store via SqlAlchemy.

As far as the table being stored in memory, I wouldn't imagine that it would be. From reading the SqlAchemy documentation, the Table object is SqlAlchemy is just a proxy to the underlying table in whatever database is backing the system. In general, you wouldn't want the table in memory since you don't know how many messages the system will process, how big the e-mail messages are, and how many messages need to be queued in case of a temporary mail sending failure.